# How to load Tableau in Salesforce Visualforce via the Tableau Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, tableau-api

I'd like to load the following Tableau Javascript Code within Salesforce Visualforce. Although it works, in a browser (see codepen [here](http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/PNXWXQ?editors=1000)), I get the below error in the console when I put it in Salesforce Visualforce.

I utilize Tableau Online and not Tableau Server.

```
<apex:page >
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://10ay.online.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js'></script><div class='tableauPlaceholder' style='width: 1444px; height: 673px;'><object class='tableauViz' width='1444' height='673' style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2F10ay.online.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;curalate' /><param name='name' value='test&#47;Sheet1' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='showShareOptions' value='true' /></object></div>


</apex:page>
```

Error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Refused to display 'https://10ay.online.tableau.com/&#47;t&#47;curalate/views/test&#47;Sheet1?:…reOptions=true&:display_spinner=no&:loadOrderID=0&:increment_view_count=no' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Comment: Salesforce requires a framework, Canvas, for integrating 3rd party tools like Tableau. Check out this link for more information. http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/2/salesforce-canvas-connector-tableau-server-online-live-36973